# How to reduce independent set to longest path

Tags: algorithms, graphs, np

A friend and I have tried for several hours to try and find a reduction from  independent set to longest path, but the results have not been fruitful. We have tried many methods of graphing and complementing but are well and truly lost. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Find any method to prove longest path is NP-hard; that can be used to find any reduction from any NP problem to it.  There are questions here that describe how to prove longest path NP-hard.